# Chessboard Camera Calibration using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, stereo-3d

I am trying to compute the distance of an object from the camera using stereo vision approach. But before computing the disparity map, I must ensure that my cameras are calibrated.

I followed the opencv python tutorial on camera calibration. They have used a chessboard to calibrate their cameras. Now my question is, if I want to calibrate my cameras, do I need to click photos of a chessboard from various angles manually? Or can I use the 14 chessboard images they have made available?

My next question (depending on the answer to the previous question) is, if I can use their images to calibrate my cameras, what is the logic behind this? How can images clicked from their cameras be used to calibrate my cameras, i.e. get the camera matrix for my cameras? I would like to get more intuition behind this camera calibration process.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you have answered your own question. Q) How are pictures taken from another camera going to be able to be used to calibrate *your* camera? A) They're not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- No, you print something similar with a chessboard pattern and you use it to calibrate your own camera. You can use code at [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html).

2- The process basically goes like this: To determine coordinate of a pixel in an image, you need to know two(counting only most fundamental ones, currently I exclude distortion parameters) set of parameters. First set of parameters are inner parameters of your camera (intrinsic parameters) are optical center of your camera (basically center pixel of your sensor/lens) and focal length of your camera. Intrinsic parameters are fixed for your camera unless you change some settings of the device or some settings change with time. Second set of parameters are a position and rotation vector that describes where your camera is in the 3D world (these are extrinsic parameters). Extrinsic parameters change for every example image you have. You can think of camera calibration as an optimization process that tries to find best parameters (parameters that give minimum reprojection error) for the example images you have given.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer! Are there any specifics or good practices I need to follow while taking those pictures to calibrate my camera?

Comment: Yes, 14 images are usually not enough due to sensor errors and inaccuracies of detected points. So you almost always want to take more images when calibrating your camera. I remember OpenCV (and probably MATLAB, but not sure) had good camera calibration tools that show you how much more images you need to show to your camera during calibration. They basically show how much diversity you need in your chessboard images (board at different X/Y positions, different rotations and skew...). Also make sure corner points of the chessboard are visible in calibration images, more accurate points better.